# Duplicate GitHub repository after rename (Developer Story)

Tags: bug, developer-story, github

In recently change the name of one of my projects on GitHub, from 'Sender' (capital letter) to 'sender' (lowercase), and I removed it from the developer story timeline.
When I want to re-add it, I found out that there are 2 versions of the repository:
The new one, and the old one.
How can it be solved?

[image]

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com